# React-native TouchableOpacity button doesn't respect border/border-radius

Tags: react-native

I have created a generic button which I'd like to have round edges instead of being a square. My button component is as such:

```js
const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>
          {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = {
    textStyle: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: colors.primaryTeal,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: colors.whiteText,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        borderRadius: 50
    }
};
```

However, it remains to be square and doesn't respond to `borderRadius` at all.

It's invoked as such:

```js
<Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
    Log in
</Button>
```

How do I make it respect borderRadius and get round edges?

The login form in which it appears(Render)

```js
  render() {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                <Input
                    placeholder="user@gmail.com"
                    label="Email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                />
            </CardSection>
            <CardSection>
                <Input
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder="password"
                    label="Password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                />
            </CardSection>
            <View style={styles.btnWrapper}>
            <CardSection>
                {this.state.loading ? 
                    <Spinner size="small" /> : 
                    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                        Log in
                    </Button>}
            </CardSection>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle} disabled={this.state.error !== null}>
                {this.state.error}
            </Text>
        </Card>
```

CardSection component:

```js
const CardSection = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative'
  }
};
```

Comment: i would check CardSection styles. Might add a `flex:1` to it to span to its full space.

Comment: I just added the component, could you have a look? Adding flex: 1 broke everything though :P

Comment: @cbll try changing the backgroundColor of `CardSection` or `Button` to different colors, in your case both are white maybe that's why the border is not seen.

Comment: @RaviRaj the solution was to make a seperate CardSection for buttons, actually, and just have that set a borderRadius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works perfectly fine. Just make sure to use react native's `StyleSheet.create` to get cached styles.
Maybe your button container view background is white and you're not seeing the rounded corners.

Heres my working [snack](https://snack.expo.io/HyG3tYH-f)

Code snippet i used, but refer to the snack as you'll see it live in action.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button>
          Log in
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  textStyle: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: 'teal',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        borderRadius: 50
    },
});
```

Comment: Hmm, if I wrap it in a <View> it never even renders the button. It's strange.

Comment: How do you render it in your app tho ? Post your full screen structure in your question. Might just be a style issue.

Comment: I just added the whole component where it's rendered.

Comment: I've put in both the CardSection and render method of my LoginForm. Do they give any hints as to what is wrong?

Comment: we need to put in border width as well

Answer (score 3):

You have to add style `overflow: hidden` to `TouchableOpacity`

Comment: you can use a styled view inside touchable.

Answer (score 2):

Try add attribute borderWidth and borderColor on buttonStyle, like below:

```
 buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: colors.whiteText,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#3b5998"
}
```

A complete example:

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
        disabled={!isValid}
        style={{
          alignSelf: "center",
          marginBottom: 30,
          overflow: 'hidden',
          borderColor: "#3b5998",
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderRadius: 100,
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{               
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignSelf: "center",
            paddingLeft: 15,
            paddingRight: 15,
            minHeight: 40,
            alignItems: 'center',                
            
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold", color: "#3b5998" }}>
            SEND
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the `containerStyle` prop

```
<TouchableOpacity containerStyle={ViewStyleProps}>
```